# Evaluate helpers is same context as tested file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, eval

I would like to test prototype functions that I make.

My set up consist of 3 files:

- Base.js - Base file, that all my second files have in common

  ```
  function prop(to, name, func) {
      Object.defineProperty(to.prototype, name, {
          value: func,
          writable: true,
          configurable: true
      });
      return func;
  }
  ```
- Array.js - file that modify the prototype of given Object.

  ```
  prop(Array, 'hasPresent', function(what) {
      return !!~this.indexOf(what)
  });
  ```
- /tests/Array.js - Test itself

  ```
  describe('hasPresent()',function(){
      it('number', function(done){
          expect([0,1,2].hasPresent(0)).toBe(true)
          done()
      })
  })
  ```

All this is done from nodeJS, that watches file for changes. My concern is, that it will return error from second file (`prop is not defined ... at Array.js:1`). This says me, that those files are not evaluated in same context. Is there any way to make this work? Or how to get `__direcotory` variable in test file, when started from node.

My setup in nodejs:

```
jasmine.loadConfig({
    spec_files: ['Base.js','Array.js']
    helpers: ['Base.js','Array.js']
})

jasmine.execute(['tests/Array.js']);
```

PS.: I tried putting eval in `tests/Array.js`, but the working directory is forgotten when loaded, so I would have to use absolute path, if there is any way to work around this, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the normal module mechanism for Node.js: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Here is the basic example which you can adapt to your testing:

The contents of foo.js:

```
const circle = require('./circle.js');
console.log(`The area of a circle of radius 4 is ${circle.area(4)}`);
```

The contents of circle.js:

```
const PI = Math.PI;
exports.area = (r) => PI * r * r;
exports.circumference = (r) => 2 * PI * r;
```

Comment: I understand, that making it the module way would be a way to go, but my library contains prototypes only, and afterward the file is send to browsers, so I don't want to modify them for node.